# jQuery AJAX - Uploading file using FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

I am trying to upload file using AJAX in WordPress administration. Here is my code:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#upload_app").click(function(e)
                {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                            event.preventDefault();

                    var data = new FormData();

                    aaa = document.getElementById("path_to_file");

                    alert(aaa.files[0]);

                    data.append("newFile",aaa.files[0]);

                    alert(data["newFile"]);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "'.get_site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/move_and_match/upload_file.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: uploadDone,
                        error: uploadFailed
                    });
                });
            });

            function uploadDone(returns)
            {
                alert(returns);
                $("#uploadFileMetaBox p").text("Successfull.");
            }

            function uploadFailed(returns)
            {
                alert(returns);
                $("#uploadFileMetaBox p").text("Problem occured.");
            }
</script>
```

AJAX access PHP script without problems but no files are sent. As you can see I added some alerts to the script. First one `alert(aaa.files[0]);` works without problems but the second one (when the value of aaa should be inserted into FormData object) says that the value is `undefined`.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A43wR/)

What am I doing bad?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Not sure why this is failing for you, since your AJAX call looks just like the accepted answers in the related questions.

Comment: You could try using the Ajax Form plugin.

Comment: Do you have any more context? E.G how you're uploading the file, how you're identifying the file? etc etc

Comment: Is it possible that WordPress somehow blocks FormData?

Comment: @RichPeck In my PHP is only: if(isset($_GET['files']))
{ 
 echo json_encode("FILES SENT");
}
else
{
 echo json_encode("NO FILES SENT");
}

Comment: What about the Wordpress upload side of things? Like how you're sending the files?

Comment: The FormData object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using XMLHttpRequest. Its primarily intended for use in sending form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to transmit keyed data. The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set to "**multipart/form-data**". - from mozilla

Comment: @RichPeck I added Meta Box into Post edit page and there is file input and button. That button violates that AJAX. I just don't know why the data content is still undefined. When I try to alert only data object I get correct feedback.

Comment: Have you tried just sending some data (not a file) to see if the Ajax actually fires?

Comment: Where this come from? `aaa = document.getElementById("path_to_file");` what is `path_to_file`?

Comment: It is file input element's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it you want to send files using javascript (AJAX)

because if security you can't access to files and paths of files added by browse button with javascript. And as I know you should send it by a form.

And the way that I know is to use a hidden `<iframe>` `<form>`:

> 1. You should have a HTML `<iframe>` element in your body of create it with javascript
> 2. Want to do the AJAX thing en an event right? like onclick of upload button or onchange the browse file input so you should do (call ajaxUpload(iframeObj) when you want to submit the form)
> 3. The'ajaxUpload()' function will set the target of form to the iframe and the will submit your form.
> 4. we have added a listener for iframe's onload so when the form uploads and the results came from server the iframeReady function will called and then the content of iframe will be fetched (here is the url of uploaded image)
>      5.(attention the output that you send in PHP file should be covered by HTML and body tags cause we can get the iframe's body content)

**The whole idea is this** and I have tested please let me know if still there is any problem.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function ajaxUpload(mf){
      $(mf).prop('target',#hiddenIframe');
      $(mf).submit();
      $('#hiddenIframe').on('load',function(){
        IframeReady();
      }
    }

    function getFrameContents(iFrame){
       var iFrameBody;
       if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
       { // FF
         iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       }
       else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
       { // IE
         iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       }
        return iFrameBody.innerHTML;
    }

    function IframeReady(){
      var miframe=$('#hiddenIframe');
      var result;
      var $odiv=$('#result');
      result=getFrameContents(miframe);
      $odiv.html(result);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe" style="width:0;height:0;display:none;"></iframe>
<div class="result" id="resultBox">Result will be displayed here.</div>
<form action="/saveImage_ajax.php" method="POST" enctype="form/multipart">
Please upload your image: <input type="file" name="mimg" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="ajaxUpload(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
```

PHP file (saveImage_ajax.php) (or anything you want.)

```
<?php

// do some stuff to save Image In a location.

$ret= json_encode(array('status'=>'ok','src'=>'the destination of image file'));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $ret;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Is it possible that it doesn't work because these inputs aren't in form object ? It is in WordPress editing page and I am not able to insert form there.

Comment: okay lets solve it together. But before that give me links of your page and full description of what you want to do and what you want to reach. Because I think there are other ways to reach the goal.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't give you access because it is web which I am doing for my company. In short: I have file input and button. That button should not submit form but call another PHP file using AJAX and that file will upload file selected in the input. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry for my late reply I was offline. So you have a form for example takes an Image from user by browse button and you want to upload Image without refreshing and with AJAX right? And maybe show the preview of the Uploaded Image right? The way that I know is using an iframe and form.

Answer (score 0):

- `FormData` object do not expose any of its items so there is no `data["newFile"]`.
- Your url is totally wonky. `'.get_site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/move_and_match/upload_file.php` is not the url want maybe

  ```
  url: "<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/wp-content/plugins/move_and_match/upload_file.php",
  ```
- Your use of `event` while your event parameter is `e` will crap out on browsers that do not set the *global* `event` object. You should rename it to event. `function(event){`

Comment: And then... How should I "find" that file in PHP?

Comment: @HonzaKopecky The file can be found in [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Maybe, it can be my problem.. I used $_POST["input_name"] / $_GET["input_name"]... So I should use $_FILES["input_name"] ?

Comment: @HonzaKopecky use it for files only files.